# Access and modify JSON-Object via string path

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, string, object

my question is simple but nobody in the web seemed to have answered it and I can't get my head around it.

I basically want to write a setter function which takes a JSON-Object and sets a key to a value, no matter if the path already exists or not.

Variant 1:

```js
setPath(payload: Object, path: string, value: any) {
 // ???
}

obj: Object = {}
newObj: Object = setPath(obj, "foo.bar[0], "wut");
```

Variant 2:

```js
setPath(payload: Object, path: string, value: any){
 // ???
}
obj: Object {
 foo: {
  bar: []
 }
}
newObj: Object = setPath(obj, "foo.bar[0]", "wut");
```

Where both of them would result in a JSON-Object looking like this:

```js
{
 foo: {
  bar: [
   "wut" 
  ]
 }
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: https://youmightnotneed.com/lodash#set

Comment: You have to parse your path expression and then traverse the target object graph step by step until you've gotten to the last target object, and then set the property value. Exactly how that looks depends on what you need your path expressions to look like. (For example, should your path be able to include property names with spaces or embedded "." characters?)

Comment: Thanks to @cmgchess I just solved it with lodash xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @cmgchess,

https://youmightnotneed.com/lodash#set

At this link you can either find a plain JavaScript solution or, as I did, just use the method lodash provides to you